# How to test an if-condition not been excuted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to Rspec. I have a code like this:

```
if @context.persona == :system && @context.scopes&.include?(SEARCH_SCOPE)
  return <something>
end
```

I want to write a unit test to confirm the `@context.scopes&.include?(SEARCH_SCOPE)` is not being executed when @context.persona is not :system. Here is what I wrote:

```
context 'when persona is system' do
  let(:persona) { :system }
  
  it 'checks the scope' do
     allow(context).to receive(:scopes)

     expect(context).to have_received(:scopes)
  end
end

context 'when persona is not system' do
  let(:persona) { :user }
  
  it 'checks the scope' do
     allow(context).to receive(:scopes)

     expect(context).not_to have_received(:scopes)
  end
end
```

The second test passed, but the first test failed with:

```
     Failure/Error: expect(context).to have_received(:scopes)
     
       (Double (anonymous)).scopes(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Could someone help me? I googled it before but didn't see anything helpful. I'm sorry if it is duplicated.

Comment: It is likely that `@context.persona == :system` is `false` and thus `@context.scopes&.include?(SEARCH_SCOPE)` is never reached. I am not sure what this `let(:persona) { :system }` is supposed to do but it without understanding what `context` is in the test it will be very difficult to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you are falling into the pit of **testing implementation, instead of behaviour**. Don't do that.

Your test shouldn't care about this:

```
expect(context).not_to have_received(:scopes)
```

Instead, your test should only be doing something like this:

```
context 'when persona is system and scopes includes SEARCH_SCOPE' do
  let(:persona) { :system }
  let(:scopes) { ... }
  
  it 'returns <something>' do
     expect(the_method_being_invoked).to eq(<something>)
  end
end

context 'when persona is not system' do
  let(:persona) { :user }
  let(:scopes) { ... }
  
  it 'returns <something-else>' do
     expect(the_method_being_invoked).to eq(<something-else>)
  end
end

context 'when scopes is empty' do
  let(:persona) { :user }
  let(:scopes) { nil }
  
  it 'returns <something-else>' do
     expect(the_method_being_invoked).to eq(<something-else>)
  end
end
```

Why? Because when you refactor code, and the implementation changes, you don't want specs to start failing unless the **behaviour** has also changed.

You should usually even be able to write the test before writing the method -- therefore having no knowledge of its implementation details.

Comment: Note: Sorry my spec definitions are a bit fuzzy, but I had to leave quite a few blanks. If the original examples were more complete, then my answer would be equally complete.